# Is there a script that posts git commits to twitter?

Tags: git, twitter

Git is notorious by its encouraged length limit for commit message titles: first line should not be more than 50 characters long (to fit an e-mail header).

That reminds me of... well, is there a hook that automatically posts commit messages to twitter as soon as they're pushed to the server?

Comment: What a bizarre idea. Like it.

Comment: The limit is encouraged; not forced upon the user.

Comment: @Htbaa, or course, but what that means is that git users most likely have a culture of making short messages.

Comment: Nah... I just do as I please :-)

Answer (score 14):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/sh
username=<your Twitter account>
password=<your Twitter password>

service_uri=http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json

subject=`git log --pretty=format:%s -n1`

curl -u "${username}:${password}" -d status="${subject}" $service_uri
```

Save as `.git/hooks/post-commit` in your repository and make it executable.

[Note: completely untested, I just made this up on the spot.]

Comment: A suggestion: this should be a post-receive hook, which runs on the remote after you've pushed to it. It gets on stdin all the refs that were updated: "<old-value> <new-value> <ref-name>" so you can do something like `while read line; do fields=($line); subject="$(git log --pretty=format:%s ${fields[0]}..${fields[1]})"; ....; done`.

Comment: This does not work as Twitter no longer supports basic authentication

Answer (score 6):

Github does this with their ["Service Hooks" feature](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/). The code for it is here: [github/github-services/lib/services/twitter.rb](https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/master/lib/services/twitter.rb)

Comment: since 2019-01-31 this service has been discontinued, unfortunately: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/replacing-github-services/

Answer (score 5):

I set up a Git post-commit hook that posts to my private Twitter account each time I make a local commit on my development repository. Here's what I did:

1. Register an application with Twitter. Here’s how you do that:

   1. Go to http://dev.twitter.com. You may need to sign in again.
      http://www.adornomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screen-Shot-2013-04-02-at-5.12.18-PM-300x290.png
   2. Hover over your avatar in the top-right, and choose “My Applications” from the menu that appears.
      http://www.adornomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screen-Shot-2013-04-02-at-5.22.26-PM.png
   3. Click on the “Create New Application” Button.
      http://www.adornomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screen-Shot-2013-04-02-at-5.23.14-PM.png
   4. Fill out the next however you’d like. The website address can be anything. The name of the app can be anything. Leave **Callback URL** blank. Agree to the agreement, enter the CAPTCHA and you’re good to go.
      http://www.adornomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screen-Shot-2013-04-02-at-5.36.56-PM-300x122.png
   5. Next, you’ll be taken to a screen with a bunch of keys. Copy all of those down into a text editor.
   6. Click the “Settings” tab. Change to “Read and Write” for **Application Type**. Click **Update**.
      http://www.adornomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screen-Shot-2013-04-02-at-5.36.42-PM-300x127.png
   7. Go back to the **Details** tab. Scroll down to the bottom and click “Create my OAuth Access Token.”
   8. Wait a few seconds, refresh the page, wait some more. Eventually, at the bottom of the page a section should appear that says **“Your access token.”** Copy these codes down.
   9. That’s it for your Twitter App setup.
2. Open up a shell on the machine you are planning to be commit to (and tweet from).
3. Install [http_post](http://acme.com/software/http_post/). You will have to compile this from source. (`make` and `make install`). Make sure it’s accessible from your `PATH`.
4. Install [oauth_sign](http://acme.com/software/oauth_sign/). You will also have to compile this form source. (**make** and **make install**) Make sure it’s accessible from your `PATH`.
5. Finally, save the following script into *.git/hooks/post-commit* in your Git repository.

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh

   # PATH modification needed for http_post and oauth_sign
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

   toplevel_path=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
   toplevel_dir=`basename "$toplevel_path"`

   branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
   subject=`git log --pretty=format:%s -n1`
   hashtags="#code #$toplevel_dir"
   tweet=$hashtags' ['$branch']: "'$subject'"'

   # truncate tweets that are longer than 140 characters
   if [ ${#tweet} -gt 140 ]
       then
           tweet_trunc=$(echo $tweet | cut -c1-137)
           tweet=${tweet_trunc}...
   fi

   consumer_key="<Put your computer key here>"
   consumer_secret="<Put your consumer secret here>"
   access_token="<Put your access token here>"
   access_secret="<Put your access token secret here>"
   url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

   http_post -h Authorization "$(oauth_sign \
   $consumer_key $consumer_secret \
   $access_token $access_secret \
   POST "$url" status="$tweet")" \
        "$url" status="$tweet"
   ```
6. Make sure that you make the file executable. (`chmod a+x .git/hooks/post-commit`)
7. That’s it! If you want to have this automatically added to any new repositories you make, modify the git-core templates. You’ll have to figure out where those are (it’s different for every setup). For me, they’re located here: */opt/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-commit*.

**Note:** This is all based heavily on this script: http://fanf.livejournal.com/108436.html

Good luck!

--David

Comment: Where would I get http_post and oauth_sign for Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Some googling discovered [friedcode](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/friedcode). Haven't tried it myself but it seems to do the job.

Comment: From that page: "the script ... contains some horrible python one-liners" -- and indeed it does :-)  Thanks for the link, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to code anything you can use https://gitweet.io

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but a while back I wrote this guy: https://github.com/mrsnowf1ake/twitter-git-hook

You can surround any part of the commit with `_*` and `*_`. It isn't exactly what you mentioned here but it does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/and-computers/HowToTweetEveryCommit

It's a shell script that runs a python script to post your commit messages to a twitter account. you need provide the 4 tokens for your account as stated in some of the other answer by creating a twitter application at https://apps.twitter.com/

Good luck!